# How do I create a smooth slope to join 2 planes of different elevation?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm trying to model a slope to connect 2 different planes together as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RPTA.jpg),[image] but I'm not sure how to do it. I've tried using the sculpt tool but it did not give me the desired effect. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXGpd.jpg) is what I want the slope to look like. How should I go about modelling this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To create such a slope is fairly simple.
Create a row of verities at the top and bottom of the slope. Make sure that the rows have the same amount of verities. Then you can bridge the gap.

If you want to create a bulge/indent, add a few edge loops running down the slope. next using proportional editing <kbd>o</kbd>, drag the center edge loop up or down. Using these techniques you can mold you slope. I would recommend sculpting for fine tuning.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Bsurfaces *Add Surface* feature.

The process is as follows.

1. Add any object, enter edit mode and delete all the vertices.
2. Place the *3D Cursor* where you want the surface to start. Place the 3D cursor in a view that is 90° from the view you will be drawing the strokes in. (all following steps will be with the cursor placed from the top view and drawing a surface along the `Y` axis)
3. Go to the front view <kbd>NumPad 1</kbd> hold <kbd>D</kbd> and draw a [grease pencil](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Sketching/Drawing) stroke at the height you want the surface to start at.
4. Go back to the top view <kbd>NumPad 7</kbd> and move the 3D Cursor down along the `Y` axis.
5. Back in the front view draw a grease pencil stroke lower then the first stroke. (**important draw all the strokes in the same direction.**)
6. Repeat steps 4 and 5, far as many steps you need for your surface. (at this point you could rotate the view to get an idea of what the surface will look like.)
7. in the tools panel (<kbd>T</kbd>) **Tools > Bsurfaces > Add Surface**. That is about it, you can adjust the options to fine tune how many loops will be created.
   [image: Bsurfaces' options]

Note if you have a set vertex count you want to start from (bridge to and from) you can start by selecting the vertices, and then drawing the strokes. The selected row of vertices will be the starting point of the surface.

Some great videos from the author of the addon on using Bsurfaces on [vimeo](http://vimeo.com/user572057/videos).
Also the [Bsurfaces quick guide](https://app.box.com/s/5ygw6vkzxkag9dh53uuv) a pdf.